# ID Number Generator

Tags: c#

I keep getting an "int cannot convert to bool" error at `if(number % NUMINROW)`, and I do not know how to fix it. I am fairly new to C#, but I know Python and how for loops work, but I am still confused.

```
// Program displays every possible ID number for a company
// ID number is a letter, followed by a two-digit number
// For example -- A00 or Z99
// Go to a new display line after every 20 IDs

using static System.Console;
class DebugFive3
{
   static void Main()
   {
      char letter;
      int number;
      const int LOW = 0;
      const int HIGH = 99;
      const int NUMINROW = 20;
      for(letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; ++letter)
        for(number = LOW; number >= HIGH; ++number)
        {
         if(number % NUMINROW)
             WriteLine();
           Write("{0}{1} ", letter, number.ToString("D2"));
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: What line does the compiler indicate has your error? I assume it's this one :`if (number % NUMINROW)`?

Comment: Maybe you want `number % NUMINROW == 0` ?

Comment: @yaakov yes it's if(number % NUMINROW)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Notice the `using static System.Console;` at the top...

Comment: @RufusL nope, need glasses evidentially. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error on second for and in condition `if(number % NUMINROW)`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char letter;
        int number;
        const int LOW = 0;
        const int HIGH = 99;
        const int NUMINROW = 20;
        for (letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; ++letter)
        {
            for (number = LOW; number <= HIGH; ++number)
            {
                if (number % NUMINROW == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine();
                else
                    Console.Write("{0}{1} ", letter, number.ToString("D2"));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting that compile error is that `number % NUMINROW` returns the remainder after dividing `number` by `NUMINROW`, which is an `int`, whereas an `if` condition must return a `bool` (and there is no implicit conversion from `int` to `bool` in C#).

One way to fix this is to modify the condition so that it compares the result of the modulus operation to another int, for example:

```
if(number % NUMINROW == 0)
```

---

**Other Issues**

1. There is no `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of the `Main` method, so as soon as the data is displayed, the console window will dissapear. Adding this line will pause execution until the user presses the `Enter` key, giving them time to see the data.
2. This condition is incorrect: `number = LOW; number >= HIGH`. It reads, *"set number to `LOW`, then loop while number is greater than or equal to `HIGH`."* That condition will never be true!! We should use `<=` instead.
3. The current code is completely ignoring the 20th column. To solve this, we can remove the `else` clause and switch the order of the code lines so that we *always* write the value, and then conditionally add a new line.
4. Assuming we want `NUMINROW` columns displayed, our modulus condition should compare the *next* number to this value, since we're starting at `0` (so the first row would be `0`-`19`, followed by `20`-`39`). Another reason to add one to the value before doing the comparison is that `0` modulus *any* number is `0`, so we would have an extra new line before the first item (where `number` is `0`).
5. Not a problem, really, but since we don't use the variables `letter` or `number` outside the loops, it's generally better to declare them as part of the `for` loop itself, to reduce their scope.

Here's a sample of how to solve these issues:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int LOW = 0;
    const int HIGH = 99;
    const int NUMINROW = 20;

    for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++)
    {
        for (int number = LOW; number <= HIGH; number++)
        {
            Write("{0}{1} ", letter, number.ToString("D2"));
            if ((number + 1) % NUMINROW == 0) WriteLine();
        }
    }

    ReadLine(); // Wait for user input
}
```

**Output**
[image]

---

As a side note, here's a fun little sample using `System.Linq` that does it all in one line (not recommended, since it's hard to read/debug, but thought it might be interesting):

```
const int LOW = 0;
const int HIGH = 99;
const int NUMINROW = 20;

WriteLine(string.Concat(Enumerable.Range('A', 26)
    .Select(chr => string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(LOW, HIGH + 1)
        .Select(num => $"{(char) chr}{num:D2}" + ((num + 1) % NUMINROW == 0
            ? Environment.NewLine : " "))))));

ReadLine();
```

Comment: To expand on this - some other languages such as Python and Javascript can treat non-boolean values as though they are "true" or "false", which is probably why you expected it to work without the `== 0`. C# intentionally does not do this.

Comment: adding the ==0 did help with the error. Thank you! But there is no output, hmmm

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ that doesn't change anything, but thank you for the feedback

Comment: `But there is no output` can you describe in better details, have you set breakpoints and inspected what `letter` and `number` are?

Comment: @Matty-LouJames You probably need to add a `Console.ReadKey()` (or similar) to pause the application (waiting for user input) the end of your `Main` method, otherwise it will just run and exit right away.

Comment: @Matty-LouJames Also there's a problem with this condition: `number = LOW; number >= HIGH`. It reads, "set `number` to `LOW`, then loop while `number` is greater than or equal to `HIGH`. So that will never run. Try `<=` instead. :)

Comment: @Matty-LouJames also, you probably want to test `(number + 1) % NUMINROW`, since we want the first row to be `0`, `20`, `30`, so we'll need the new line added *before* that number.

Comment: @RufusL Wow, this was so helpful. And it actually helped me understand for loops a lot better. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, glad it helped! :)